# Forwarding logs to logger microservice

Tags: node.js, logging, microservices

We are planning to build a microservice for logging activities of other microservices.
Logger microservice will receive all the logs and stores them properly.
Finally, we can see the logs with tools like Kibana.

I want to know what's the proper way to send log data to the logger service.

- Make an HTTP request to the logger.
- Publish logs data to a message broker and logger consumes them. (like RabbitMQ)

or any other suitable way to do this.

Thank you all.

Answer (score -1):

Why do you need to build a microservice?

Filebeat scans for service logs and ships them to logstash, managing considerations like retries, etc.

Logstash persists the logs (e.g. to Elasticsearch for Kibana to query) for consumption by other things.

Comment: Ok, can you explain more, what does it log and how?but consider that in all of our services, we have http requests

Comment: Your service just needs to do regular logging to log files.  Filebeat scans for log files and delivers the logs to logstash, which writes them to elasticsearch (logstash can also do a lot of fancy parsing of the log entries before writing the entries to elasticsearch).

Comment: If I'm not mistaken it only logs container output. Am I right? And as you said, we only need to send logs with for example console.log to the container output, is it correct?

Comment: Yeah, that's all you need to do.  Even if logging to a file within the container, filebeat can be configured on the host to scan for those files, or you can build it as a sidecar to the container.